# Boot order of MySQL

Tags: boot, mysql, upstart, init.d

I have a conflict with two programs in Ubuntu 10.04.

I have configured an `init.d` file that boots up a program. However, this program requires MySQL to be running before it starts. When I boot the machine, it's obvious that this script is being executed before MySQL has booted successfully.

I'm pretty inexperienced with Ubuntu's booting sequences and run levels. How can I make sure that MySQL is running **before** my `init.d` script is executed? I have heard that MySQL uses an alternative method of booting to `init.d` so I'm not sure how to go about this.

Thanks!

Comment: By the way: you could also have your script start mysql at boottime and not let mysql start itself during boot ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10.04 came with the new upstart system.

Here is an example of a start/stop mysql upstart: http://karlssonondatabases.blogspot.nl/2010/12/ubunto-upstart-for-automatic-mysql.html

Have a look at the `start on` part:

```
#
# MySQL Service for Recorded Future
#
description     "MySQL Server"
author          "Anders Karlsson, Recorded Future"

start on (net-device-up
          and local-filesystems
          and runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [016]

expect fork
kill timeout 2
...
```

This tells the system that mysql has to start when this is true:

```
net-device-up
      and local-filesystems
      and runlevel [2345])
```

and has to stop when this is true:

```
runlevel [016]
```

So what you can do is create an upstart script for your program based on thise example and include a `start on mysql` telling it to start after mysql has started.

---

More info on upstart:

> - [Ubuntu cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the `script` stanza is it possible to execute a bash script located in `/etc/scripts/`? Would the `exec` statement work with a bash script?

Comment: @kieran yes ofcourse. You just use the whole path with the script name to execute it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Solved it with a `start on started mysql` upstart job.